# How to apply a change of concentration and brightness of image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, brightness, contrast

I want to apply a modification of the concentration and the brightness of an image and I found  [this example in opencv and python](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-7ApjXCqh4611J3OPQ7lOAp4uqORUNn0dm5K3Mezc8Y/pub) ,but it dont supported with my version of opencv ,  [i want to get this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9ryf.png)
using opencv 3 and python3 can any one help me

Comment: Folks will only be able to help you if you provide some code and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question